# Calling functions from multiple files within a single load statement using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve the most basic *include* with `jQuery`, that is loading functions from multiple files when the DOM is ready, but apparently it turned out not to be so trivial:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Hello world!");
        foo();
        bar();
    });
</script>
```

**scripts.js**

```
function foo(){
        alert("Hello from foo!");
}

function bar(){
        alert("Hello from bar!");
}
```

With `alert("Hello world!");` being the only statement that executes as expected. The folder locations are checked, as worked with the previous strategy (`window.attachEvent`)

I've tried moving the `.ready()`statement to the `scripts.js` file but that didn't helped much.

Any advice would me really appreciated. Thanks much in advance.

**UPDATE**

Currently I'm handling the function loading this way:

```
// Based on "Flexible JavaScript events" by John Resig: http://goo.gl/xLn4S
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
    if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
        obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
        obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
        obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
    } else
        obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
}

function removeEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
    if ( obj.detachEvent ) {
        obj.detachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
        obj[type+fn] = null;
    } else
        obj.removeEventListener( type, fn, false );
}

addEvent(window, 'load', foo);
addEvent(window, 'load', bar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` is executed after the dom is complete which can happen before the external javascript files are downloaded so foo and bar may not be defined yet.

Comment: thanks for your contribution! So what would be the strategy to load multiple functions from different files?

Comment: Nano, have you tried $(window).load instead of  $(document).ready?

Comment: You could try the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), `$('body').load`

Comment: with `$(window)load()` happens the exact same thing.

Comment: with `$('body').load()` nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a typo. It's *alert* not *altert*:

```
function foo(){
        alert("Hello from foo!");
}

function bar(){
        alert("Hello from bar!");
}
```

Tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can help with things like that.

Comment: thanks for the head's up! I've fixed it. I've used those here just to illustrate, the functions I'm dealing with all have "real" names.

Comment: Can you verify that res/script.js is loading at all?

Comment: It's definitely loading, plus on production I'm using `window.attachEvent` to fire the functions, but that approach doesn't seem to work then you're dealing with more than two functions.

Answer (score 1):

First, add a unique number to the url you use to retrieve your javascript, as in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/scripts.js?111010101"></script>
```

to assure the browser retrieves the most current version of scripts.js. Then, every time the page is retrieved, generate a new unique version number. (At least during development)

Next, you need to assure that script.js has been loaded and correctly evaluated before you try to call its functions.

One way to do this would be to trigger a new, custom event at the bottom of script.js, on which you would set a handler to execute (in document.ready()).

Another way would be to load the script within the document.ready() handler before you tried to call any of its functions.

EDIT to add example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.ready(function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
    $.getScript('res/scripts.js', function() {
      foo();
      bar();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, although this approach sounds like a bit of an overhead (wouldn't `Ctrl+F5` suffice to assure a clean load?) I might try it.

Comment: True, but using a unique attribute guarantees it, irrespective of any browser's eccentricities.

Comment: I've tried `$.getScript()` with no different results. A quick note about your edit: shouldn't it be `$(document).ready()` instead of `document.ready()`?