# Animating element background image when hovering another element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to switch the `background` image of an element (e.g. `body`) when hovering another (e.g. `nav`), having some sort of fade transition between the two images using jQuery.

I've been reading similar questions at stackoverflow and tried almost every example without much luck.

*Resources*

- index.html
- styles.css
- scripts.js
- background.png
- background-hover.png

*Snippets*

**index.html**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**styles.css**

```
body {
    background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

**scripts.js**

```
$('nav')
    .mouseenter(function(){
        $('body').css("background", "url('background-hover.jpg') no-repeat");
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $('body').css("background", "url('background.jpg') no-repeat");
    });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Are you attaching those handlers on `$(document).ready(...` ?

Comment: Actually no, I'm loading the container function with many others via `window.attachEvent`/`window.addEventListener`/`document.addEventListener`

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are able to change the background, but you want it to fade in/out instead of instantly changing?

Comment: I'm currently unable to change the background as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a fade transition inbetween your backgrounds, it can't be done by solely changing the `background-image` from one to another. You'll need to at least create one other element which you can fadeIn and out. For example like this:

```
var d = $('<div />').width($('body').width())
    .height($(window).height())
    .attr('id','fakebody').hide().appendTo($('body'));

$('nav').hover(function(){
     $(d).fadeIn();
},function(){
     $(d).fadeOut();   
});

#fakebody{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
background:    url(background.jpg);
        z-index:-99;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/bXMKJ/

If you want the current image to fadeOut while the other one fades in, then you will need to have 2 dummy elements, because you can't fade the `body` (at least with the results you'd expect).

If you just want the `background-image` to change from one to another, then you can fix your code by removeing the `;` at the end of the mouseenter function, like this:

```
$('nav').mouseenter(function(){
        $('body').css("background", "url('background-hover.jpg') no-repeat");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('body').css("background", "url('background.jpg') no-repeat");
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/sC5rd/

Comment: @Niklas: Wow, I'm impressed! (loved jsfiddle thing as well) Thanks __much__ for your help!

Comment: @Niklas: May I ask you an additional question -- how would you wrap this code in a function that would be placed in an external file then loaded via `document.addEventListener`?

Comment: @Nano assuming you got jquery on your page, just make sure that this code isn't run before DOM is ready

Comment: @Niklas: thanks much. I've added the function to the current event loader although I'd love to simplify that code using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231721/calling-functions-from-multiple-files-within-a-single-load-statement-using-jquery

Comment: @Niklas: I'm doing exactly that but I thought a more succinct approach would be possible using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be...

```
$('nav').mouseenter(function(){
        $('body').css("background", "url('background-hover.jpg') no-repeat");
    });
$('nav').mouseleave(function(){
        $('body').css("background", "url('background.jpg') no-repeat");
    });
```

Note the extra 'nav' element event binding.

Comment: I'm not sure -- assuming Jon Snook syntax is correct my code should work as well: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

Comment: That syntax is binding lots of functions onto one element, which is also fine, but you are breaking that in the code in your question by using a semicolon before the mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav').mouseenter(function(){
           $('body').css("background", "url('background-hover.jpg') no-repeat");
    });
    $('nav').mouseleave(function(){
           $('body').css("background", "url('background.jpg') no-repeat");
    });

});
```

Style:

```
nav {
    border:1px green solid;
    width:150px;
}
body {
    background-image:url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

This works but if you want to fade it in and out, you should use an another element like a "div".